# Snake game bug issue

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a snake game but sometimes the food is placed where the snake is at the moment.
I have created this code as I thought it woyld work, it runs fine but does not change anything?

```
function CreateFood() {
    food = {
        x: Math.round(Math.random()*(w-cellSize)/cellSize),
        y: Math.round(Math.random()*(h-cellSize)/cellSize),
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < snakeArray.length; i++) {
        if (snakeArray[i].x == food.x && snakeArray[i].y == food.y) {
            CreateFood();
        }  
    }
}
```

EDIT: Some methods use this like paintfoodcells method etc, and I have a paint snakecells method. What I am trying to do is if the random food location that gets generated is the same as one of the snakearrays location then it just tries again. For the whole source code go to the link provided and right click view source.
http://www.taffatech.com/Snake.html

Comment: @Siamak.A.M Please stop requesting jsFiddles. If the question doesn't contain enough information to answer the question, you should ask them to edit additional information into the question, or vote to close it.

Comment: Can you please post the entire `CreateFood()` function? This one doesn't actually return anything and will therefore "not work" by default.

Comment: @newfurniturey That probably is the entire function. You've hit upon the answer to why it "does not change anything" - it neither changes the game board nor returns a value for another function to change the board based on.

Comment: I have added some more info. There is a few methods but this is the one that I believe the problems lies in, to see all the code go to the link. -food is a global variable, this method just gets a random location on the canvas - Also it does work, it just does not redo it if the snake and food 'collide'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using recursion. When you detect that the food has the same position as the snake you create a new food object but you don't change the value of the first one. Instead try a while loop.

```
done = true;
while (done == false){
    food = {
    x: Math.round(Math.random()*(w-cellSize)/cellSize),
    y: Math.round(Math.random()*(h-cellSize)/cellSize),
};

for(var i = 0; i < snakeArray.length; i++) {
    if (snakeArray[i].x == food.x && snakeArray[i].y == food.y) {
        done = false;
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you it seems to have worked, Any idea why recursion seemed to not create a new food and overwrite the old one?

Comment: Yes, in JavaScript entering a function means entering a new scope so the variable in the outer scope is overshadowed. In other words you get a new variable with the same name that disappears wven you leave the scope

Comment: I'l remember to stick to while loop's in future, thanks again!